# What is XML tag for Work hours and Work remaining in assembla

Tags: assembla

My project is in android, we are making a internal product same as assembla, and this project is linked to assembla i.e tickets will be created in assembla. I wanted to know waht si the xml tag for `Worked hours` and `Work remaining`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems they added tag *working-hours*: Work hours remaining for the ticket.

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/breakoutdocs/Ticket_REST_API